# How to make reusable component for tabbar in react native

Tags: react-native, reusability

I have a custom tabbar component and I want to add a button with animation and I want to make reusable but I can't figured out. For example I want to use it for 1,2,3... etc icons. I don't want to decide it in the component itself.The code is like below.

```
export const TabAddButton = () => {
  const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
  const buttonSize = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const mode = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const handlePress = () => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(buttonSize, {
        toValue: 0.95,
        duration: 5,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(mode, {
        toValue: mode["_value"] === 0 ? 1 : 0,
        duration: 150,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
    ]).start();
  }; 
  const lockX = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [windowWidth / 2 - 22, windowWidth / 2 - 22 - 60],
  });
  const lockY = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-20, -75],
  });

  const noteX = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [windowWidth / 2 - 22, windowWidth / 2 - 22 + 60],
  });  
  return (
    <Box {...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject} alignItems="center">
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.secondaryView,{ left: lockX,top: lockY,}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.secondaryButton}>
          <Feather name="lock" size={24} color="#FFF" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>

      <Animated.View style={[styles.secondaryView,{ left: lockX,top: noteY,}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.secondaryButton}>
          <Foundation name="clipboard-notes" size={24} color="#FFF" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>

      <View style={[styles.button]}>
        <Animated.View style={[transform: [{ scale: buttonSize }]]}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={handlePress} style={styles.primaryButton}
          >
            <Animated.View>
              <FontAwesome5 name="plus" size={24} color="#FFF" />
            </Animated.View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Are u gonna use it as `tabBarComponent` of react-navigation > BottomTabNavigator ?

Comment: yes It is for whole tabbar but this is just one button. I added a gif to question

Comment: Those icons that'd pop-up will vary based on active-route ... or are they gonna be fixed ?

Comment: No they are same for every route

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like this

```
childButtons = [
  {
    isPrimary: false,
    iconName: 'lock',
    iconType: 'Feather',
    onPress: () => {},
  },
  {
    isPrimary: false,
    iconName: 'clipboard-notes',
    iconType: 'Foundation',
    onPress: () => {},
  },
  /** ... */
];

const AppTabSecondaryButton = ({ containerStyle, onPress, IconType, iconName }) => (
  <Animated.View style={[styles.secondaryView, containerStyle]}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.secondaryButton}>
      <IconType name={iconName} size={24} color="#FFF" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
);

const AppTabPrimaryButton = ({ containerStyle, onPress, IconType, iconName }) => {
  <View style={[styles.button]}>
  <Animated.View style={containerStyle}>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={onPress} style={styles.primaryButton}
    >
      <Animated.View>
        <IconType name={iconName} size={24} color="#FFF" />
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
</View>
};

export const TabAddButton = ({ childButtons }) => {
    /** Other stuff */
    const lockX = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [windowWidth / 2 - 22, windowWidth / 2 - 22 - 60],
  });
  const lockY = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-20, -75],
  });

  const noteX = mode.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [windowWidth / 2 - 22, windowWidth / 2 - 22 + 60],
  });

  const btnContainerStyles = [
    [styles.secondaryView, { left: lockX, top: lockY,  }],
    [styles.secondaryView, { left: lockX, top: noteY }],
    /** ... */
  ];
  return (
    <Box {...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject} alignItems="center">
      {childButtons.map(({ iconName, iconType, onPress, isPrimary }, index) => (
        isPrimary ? (<AppTabPrimaryButton /** supply props */ />) :
        (<AppTabSecondaryButton /** supply props */ />)  
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But left and top attribute for AppChildTabButton must be different for each button.

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel They are different based on location I believe *leftBtn, centerBtn, rigthBtn* .. correct ?

Comment: Yes,exactly. One of them is left ,other one is top etc

Comment: Any recommendation ?

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel Have u checked the answer? I'm not if I was able to deliver the concept I'm after...

Comment: Yes,I've checked but I can't fully comprehend

Comment: Where did come from left and top values. In childButtons or what ?

Comment: Those are going to be calculated in `TabAddButton` component as u did

Comment: Yes,but it may be 1,2,3 or more button,then what should do. Imagine this is a npm package. Just come childButton props to component from user